# Terraform backend SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm pretty new to terraform, but I'm stuck trying to setup a terraform backend to use S3.

INIT:

```
terraform init -backend-config="access_key=XXXXXXX" -backend-config="secret_key=XXXXX"
```

TERRAFORM BACKEND:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_state_lock" {
  name           = "terraform-lock"
  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5
  hash_key       = "LockID"
  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "tfbackend"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "tfbackend"
    key = "terraform"
    region = "eu-west-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    status code: 403, request id: xxxx-xxxx
```

I really am at a loss because these same credentials are used for my Terraform Infrastructure and is working perfectly fine. The IAM user on AWS also has permissions for both Dynamo & S3.

Am I suppose to tell Terraform to use a different authentication method?

Comment: Is your clock accurate or has it skewed?

Comment: No actually it turns out my secret had a slash in it, and when I double clicked and copied the secret it only copied up until the slash.

Answer (score 1):

Remove .terraform/ and try again and really double check your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I regenerate the access keys and password and works good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).